# Can't figure out how to loop until a value

Tags: php

I want to make a division thingy, basically I want it to do this

When you have 0 league points = Bronze V
When you have 10 league points = Bronze IV
When you have 20 league points = Bronze III

So basically, you will still be Bronze IV until you have exactly 20 points, so my point is, you are Bronze IV when you have 10-20 points, some one help?

```
                    <?php
                    $league = $points;
                    if ($league <= 0) {
                        $league = "Bronze V";
                    } else if ($league == 10) {
                        $league = "Bronze IV";
                    } else if ($league == 20) {
                        $league = "Bronze III";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Now, I can't get that to work, cause when someone has for example 24 points, it will show up as 24 points and not Bronze IV

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice?

Comment: wheres the other question @putvande

Comment: It has been deleted. Exactly the same question but it was closed.

Comment: not sure why this should be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want `>=`

```
<?php
if ($points >= 0) {
    $league = "Bronze V";
} elseif ($points >= 10 && $points < 20) {
    $league = "Bronze IV";
} else {
    $league = "Bronze III";
}
?>
```

for sake of make sure everything is perfect, heres a better layout

```
<?php
if ($points >= 20) {
    $league = 'Bronze III';
} elseif ($points >= 10) {
    $league = 'Bronze IV';
} else {
    $league = 'Bronze V';
}
?>
```

Comment: This way it doesn't have a value from 1 - 9.

Comment: i had just copied your base logic, Edited the code, should have been a `>= 0` and not a `<= 0`

Comment: @Ascherer this should work, but it's giving me an error that there is an unexpected < at line 498, which is line 5 for this code

Comment: Re-edited the code. Join `else` and `if` into `elseif`

Answer (score -1):

You're using the equals comparison operator `==` when it sounds like you want to use greater than or equals `>=`.

As Ascherer pointed out, having `$league = $points;` doesn't seem like a good idea. Also, you should get in the habit of using single quotes instead of double quotes, because PHP has to parse inside of double quoted strings to check if there are variables inside, which slightly reduces performance.

Here's how I would write it:

```
if($points >= 0) 
{
    $league = 'Bronze V';
} 
else if($points >= 10) 
{
    $league = 'Bronze IV';
} 
else if($points >= 20) 
{
    $league = 'Bronze III';
}
else
{
    $league = 'Undefined';
}
```

Comment: the micro-optimization of using single quotes over double quotes isn't really a big deal. Last else may not be relevant if `$points` is always greater than 0

Comment: @Ascherer You're probably right that it doesn't make a big difference -- it's just a good habit to have, I think. Regarding the `else` branch at the end, it's likely that it *shouldn't* be necessary, but I can't tell you how many hours I've lost over the years due to a variable having an unpredictable value that I didn't anticipate. For that reason, I **always** have a final `else` statement to handle the case where something goes wrong..